# What is the best UI for dashboard?

Tags: css, prototype, mockup

I am currently working on a project which requires a user dashboard. I'm toying between two options. My main concern with a minimalistic layout is that it is a waste of clicks.

I'm a huge fan of bringing the data forward (Saffer) and therefore I want to capture the basic amount of data and display that on my dashboard.

I've not done any UX testing, however my team prefer the more minimal design to start prototyping with. (I'm not sold on it). I feel the front page is slightly wasted if it's just extra click throughs.

What are people's thoughts? Please see my two wireframes:

[image: Two examples of a user dashboard. The actions are the same, but functionality is different.]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The intended user's are to do advertise, view or buy items. This is just a concept here.

Comment: The question is very general - there are too many usecases for a dashboard to judge performance by two possible scenarios - Can you probably explain some more details about the purpose of your project?

Comment: Thanks @Jan - unfortunately these are wireframes concepts. Nothing is fixed. However the main purpose is to simply create a package for selling. However for conceptual purposes, I thought maybe a user could view a summary of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the main task of your users? Is it necessary for them to see the information of the different widgets at the same time? Also, how is determined for each widget which top 4 to show (since they can view more)?

If your users will focus only on one part of the dashboard, according to their own tasks (like 'Finances and Billing') I would chose a minimal design for the home page, with small stats for each widget/section, e.g. '*20 unpaid, 41 paid*'. On the home page they will choose which part of the dashboard they go to, depending on their task. You can also offer the different sections of the dashboard by using tabs as a navigation method.

If your users need an overview of everything, show as much as possible on one screen to offer them the needed information.

Answer (score 1):

Personally the minimalistic one, the extra clicks are negligible when you take into account the amount of time it would take for a single click, the minimalistic one also makes it easier to pinpoint what you're after, rather than having all the information in your face the only information you see is exactly what you're after (which will most likely offset the extra time taken for clicks).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Good reasons! I certainly don't want to overwhelm the user! I just thought a dashboard is a place to get an overview of content. (The bare minimum summary of data). What is your definition of a portal? A dashboard?

Comment: As someone mentioned early they're very general terms, very opinionated definitions, it's all down to what sits well with the target audience, I'd suggest finding speaking to a select group of exactly who you are pitching this to and asking them what they would expect to see.